# Why does a centrocyte have a cleaved nuclei?

Tags: cell-biology, immunology, immune-system, immunity

Why does a [centrocyte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centrocyte) have a cleaved nuclei? Is there a biological reasoning behind this phenomenon or is it the nature of the centrocytes? Does the selected centrocytes proliferate too?